# YouTube Subscribe Button Callback Event

Tags: youtube

Does anyone know if the YouTube scubscribe button (the one that appears in widgets on various websites) has a callback function once the user has clicked subscribe? I have looked into making my own but due to the fact they load in iframes I dont think its possibe.

Answer (score 0):

It currently (2013-01-08) does not: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 0):

Yes they recently added a callback function. In their GUI for creating a subscribe button, you can check "My application listens for button events." and it'll include the callback in the widget code: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button

Comment: ...and now it's been deprecated: https://developers.google.com/youtube/subscribe/reference